# How do I create a dynamic parameter in ADO Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, conditional-statements, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm de-duping a pipeline and have everything working perfectly - almost.  I have 4 environments and am consolidating the deployment code into a single stage that I am looping through with an "each" statement.  I want to add a condition to the stage that will only run the stage if the parameter is true

The problem is how to construct the parameter in the looped code.  I need to only be checking the parameter that is pertinent for the current environment being deploy, but I don't seem to be able to get this working right

My code looks like this

```
parameters:
    - name: Step1
      type: boolean
      default: TRUE
    - name: Step2
      type: boolean
      default: TRUE
    - name: Step3
      type: boolean
      default: FALSE
    - name: Step4
      type: boolean
      default: FALSE
    - name: Steps
      type: object
      default:
      - step: Step1
        dependsOn: Step0
      - step: Step2
        dependsOn: Step0
      - step: Step3
        dependsOn: Step0
      - step: Step4
        dependsOn: Step3

stages:
  - stage: Step0
  
  - ${{ each step in parameters.Steps }}:
    - stage: Deploy${{ step.step }}
      displayName: Deploy ${{ step.step }}
      dependsOn: ${{ step.dependsOn }}
      condition: eq( ${{ parameters.*NAME* }}, true )
```

Here "*NAME*" is where the problem lies - I need a different value for *NAME* on each iteration so that the stage only checks the correct parameter - not all of them.  So far I've tried all sorts of ways of feeding different values into this position but have had no success yet.

What I am trying to do is to feed ${{ step.step }} into ${{ parameters.*NAME* }} so that I get the appropriate condition for the current iteration - eg: step1==true, step2==true, step3==false, and step4==false and for the pipeline to only run step1 or step2 unless I tell it otherwise

${{ parameters.${{ step.step }} }} isn't working, I can't seem to be able to construct parameters*NAME* as a variable and feed that into my condition eq( ${{ $parameterName }}, true )

I know this *SHOULD* be possible, and I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious

Am I?

Have tries many different ways of dynamically creating this value, but to no avail

Want to be able to dynamically create a parameter in a looped stage in a pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I've found a much easier way of accomplishing what I wanted - rather than trying to build the parameter, I decided to test the step name and then pass on the correct condition for  that particular step

here's how I did it

```
    stage:
    ${{ if eq( step.step , 'step1' ) }}:
      condition: eq('${{ parameters.step1 }}', true)
    ${{ if eq( step.step , 'step2' ) }}:
      condition: eq('${{ parameters.step2 }}', true)
    ${{ if eq( step.step , 'step3' ) }}:
      condition: eq('${{ parameters.step3 }}', true)
    ${{ if eq( step.step , 'step4' ) }}:
      condition: eq('${{ parameters.step4  }}', true)
```

This lets me apply the condition correctly.

Yeah, I know, this might seem obvious - but it wasn't to me - took some fiddling to get everything formatted correctly - but it's working now

If it helps someone else down the line? Great stuff - but it's at least helped me  :D